# Xamarin Studio Windows: Cannot open Xamarin Forms files

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I installed Xamarin Studio on Windows and created a Xamarin Forms project. When I try to open any file in Xamarin Studio, I get the following error.

> " File could not be opened. Method 'Getlanguageitem' in type
>   'Monodevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView' from assembly
>   'Monodevelop.SourceEditor, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' doesn't have an implementation.  "

I tried to restore NuGet Packages and reinstalled the Xamarin Studio but still get the same error.

How can I solve it? Can you use Xamarin Studio in Windows?

Comment: Xamarin Studio for Windows does no longer exist. Whatever you downloaded is not official. Visual Studio is the software you have to use in Windows

Comment: you can download it from xamarin dashboard. And latest build is September 26 2016. And this is the link.                       http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-6.1.1.15-0.msi

Comment: Which VisualStudio did you have before ?

Comment: visual studio 2015 community edition.

Comment: I would try reinstalling it. Xamarin Studio 6.1.1.15's SourceEditorView does have a GetLanguageItem method and it is working. Only Xamarin Studio 5.10 and earlier do not. If you installed over the top of Xamarin Studio 5.10 maybe the MonoDevelop.SourceEditorView.dll was not updated.

Comment: @MattWard   I uninstalled and deleted leftover files. Then installed again but I cant seem to find the Monodevelop.SourceEditorView.dll.  But thanks anyway I downloaded the vs2017 rc and and it has improved xaml editor for xamarin forms.